# Visual Studio Code Not Working WIN 7

Tags: visual-studio-code

I am using v 1.23.1 on windows 7

When I open visual code there are no other windows for the app that will show. If I Open a folder it will not show the code. If I click on File > Preferences > Settings it will not open the window (I assume a modal). I have uninstalled it several time, and removed everything out of %appdata% code. It has worked in the past, but it might have been a previous version.

I can't get to the remove extensions window to remove extensions

Version 1.23.1
Commit d0182c3
Date 2018-05-10T17:11:17.614Z
Shell 1.7.12
Renderer 58.0.3029.110
Node 7.9.0
Architecture x64.

Comment: That sounds like something you should report to the VS Code bug tracker, not like a question for SO

Comment: Actually, checking their github repository, [you have already filled a bug report there](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/50531) - why did you post a "question" here as well?

Comment: I added a question here to try to get an answer. Doubling down on my chances of getting a fix for it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I had to do this to make it work

code --disable-gpu

Comment: Yeah, It's work. But always i have to hit --disable-gpu. How can i fix it permanently.

Comment: I found out the issue was with my graphic card. I had to go in the software settings for my graphic card and there was an option to add visual studio code to a list so it would work all the time. I still don't think this is the preferred way

Answer (score 3):

As Microsoft said:
[https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/supporting/FAQ#:~:text=Microsoft%20ended%20support%20for%20Windows,later%20versions%20of%20VS%20Code](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/supporting/FAQ#:%7E:text=Microsoft%20ended%20support%20for%20Windows,later%20versions%20of%20VS%20Code).

Can I run VS Code on Windows 7?
Microsoft ended support for Windows 7 in January, 2020 and no longer provides security updates. VS Code desktop versions starting with 1.71 (August 2022) will no longer run on Windows 7 and you will need to upgrade to a newer Windows version to use later versions of VS Code.
VS Code will no longer provide product updates or security fixes on Windows 7 and VS Code version 1.70.3 is the last available release for Windows 7 users. You can learn more about upgrading your Windows version at support.microsoft.com.

I was getting the same issue so I downloaded the 1.70.2 and it started working.

https://code.visualstudio.com/updates/v1_70
https://update.code.visualstudio.com/1.70.2/win32-x64-user/stable

Comment: thanks for updates, and how to find the windows 64 bit portable (zip) version of 1.70.2 ? The web site only shows installer versions.....

Comment: @Grace you can use this link: https://update.code.visualstudio.com/1.70.2/win32-x64-archive/stable

Answer (score 0):

Follow these for permanent solution:

1. right click the visual studio icon on desktop
2. go to properties
3. go to the path
4. after the end of inverted commas"..
5. give a blankspace and type: --disable-gpu
6. press apply and ok
7. restart now.